# Lexicographic ordering of triplets of integers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, lexicographic

I have the following problem: I have an array of `N` integer triplets (i.e. an `N`x`3` matrix) and I would like to order it lexicographically in Matlab. In order to do so I thought of using the built-in `sort` algorithm of Matlab, but I wanted to ask if the way I thought of doing it is right or if there exists a simpler way (preferably using Matlab routines).

I thought of converting every triplet into a single number and then sort these numbers with `sort()`. If my integers were between 0 and 9, I could just convert them into decimal. However, they are bigger. If their maximum absolute value is `M`, I thought of converting them into the (`M`+1)-ary system like this: if (`a`,`b`,`c`) the triplet, the corresponding integer is `a*(M+1)^2+b*(M+1)+c`. Would sorting these transformed integers solve the problem, or am I making a logical mistake in my reasoning?

Thank you!

PS: I know that `sort()` in Matlab does have a lexicographic option for strings, but my integers do not have the same digit length. Maybe padding them with leading zeros and concatenating them would do the trick?

Comment: if your integers might have negative numbers than converting to `M+1`-base or padding will not work.

Comment: Fortunately, my integers are all non-negative. I understand why padding would not work, but why wouldn't (M+1)-base not work for negative integers?

Comment: Suppose `M` is 9 and you have "negative digits" what will correspond to ( 0, 0, 9 ) vs. ( 0, 1, -1 )? If I understand you correctly, both tupples will convert to `9`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using [`sortrows`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html)?
Should enable you to straight-forward sort your 3-columns of data lexicographically.